recorrer datos de un select para mostrarlos en una tabla
Hasta ahora cuando quería mostrar la consulta select de una tabla, utilizaba un foreach para recorrer el array que creaba al llamar al método de la consulta.
Pero ahora, para mostrar los datos que obtengo de tres tablas, me muestra todos los registros de la tabla.
He probado con las funciones de Mysql WHERE, LIKE, IN, ... Pero no me dan resultado.
Creo que, más bien el problema es el foreach, pero no sé cómo mostrar los datos.
Esta es la función:
function find_purchase_details(){
    global $db;
    $sql="SELECT pu.id,p.name AS name,p_d.qty AS qty,p_d.price AS price,p_d.total AS total";
    $sql.=" FROM purchase_details p_d";
    $sql.=" INNER JOIN purchases pu ON p_d.date=pu.date";
    $sql.=" INNER JOIN products p ON p_d.product_id=p.id";
    $sql.=" WHERE pu.id=p_d.purchase_id;";
    return find_by_sql($sql);
}

Y esta es la página donde los muestro:
<?php $purchase_details=find_purchase_details(); ?>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" class="table table-bordered table-striped"id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="width:50px;">#</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width:10%;">Código compra</th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width:15%;">Cantidad</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width:15%;">Precio</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width:15%;">Total</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width:100px;">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($purchase_details as $purchase_detail): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($purchase_detail['id']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo "CO".str_pad($purchase_detail['id'],4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)."/24"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo remove_junk($purchase_detail['name']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo (int)$purchase_detail['qty']; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($purchase_detail['price']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($purchase_detail['total']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="edit_purchase_detail.php?id=<?php echo (int)$purchase_detail['id']; ?>" style="margin-right:5px;" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </a>
                <a onclick="javascript:return confirm('¿Confirmar Eliminación?');" href="delete_purchase_detail.php?id=<?php echo (int)$purchase_detail['id']; ?>" style="margin-left:5px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

P. D.: Al probar el select en phpmyadmin, me muestra todo igual que en mi página, así que puede que tenga algún fallo y no sea por el foreach.

Posiblemente no sea la causa del problema, pero no necesitas esto en el WHERE: pu.id=p_d.purchase_id AND p.id=p_d.product_id ya que están de forma explíctita en los JOIN.

Lo del WHERE es el mínimo problema. Antes he probado a ponerlo por trozos y a quitarlo y funciona igual.

@CharlyUtrilla por lo que entiendo, el problema es la consulta, no? ¿que datos estas obteniendo que no debería? Intenta compartir un [mcve]

Me muestra todos los registros. Es lógico que así sea, pues no veo que estés filtrando ningún registro en específico en la parte WHERE de la consulta, la cual sólo tiene JOINs implícitos como comenta @Marcos. ¿Cuáles son los registros que debe mostrar? ¿Cuál es el criterio de filtrado?

En la tabla de compras, al dale a un boton que hay al lado de cada una, me lleva a otra página donde solo me deberían aparecer los objetos comprados con el id que le paso, pero me aparecen todas y cada una de las compras que he registrado en la bbdd. ¿Entonces, cómo debo hacer el where?

solo me deberían aparecer los objetos comprados con el id que le paso ... ¿... cómo debo hacer el where? Pues tú mismo te has respondido, el WHERE debería ser: SELECT laConsultaConLosJoinQueNecesites WHERE laColumnaID=el id que le paso El quid de la cuestión es filtrar por ese ID, pero NO en forma de JOIN implícito, sino directamente. Supongamos que ese ID tiene el valor 7, pues la consulta debería quedar WHERE laColumnaID=7, asumiendo que usarás consultas preparadas, claro está. Uno de los motivos por los que no se recomienda JOIN implícitos es por este tipo de confusiones.

SELECT pu.id,p.name AS name,p_d.qty AS qty,p_d.price AS price,p_d.total AS total FROM purchase_details p_d INNER JOIN purchases pu ON p_d.date=pu.date INNER JOIN products p ON p_d.product_id=p.id WHERE pu.id=p_d.purchase_id; Me sigue saliendo lo mismo, habiendo cambiado el where y el pimer join

Edita la pregunta y agrega el código de la función find_purchase_details()

Ya lo tienes, pero he decidido poner el select en la misma página para poder insertar el id en la funcion.

En los comentarios indicas que:

En la tabla de compras, al dale a un boton que hay al lado de cada
una, me lleva a otra página donde solo me deberían aparecer los
objetos comprados con el id que le paso, pero me aparecen todas y cada
una de las compras que he registrado en la bbdd

Se entiende que quieres filtrar por una compra en particular, la cual es una variable, está variable no la estas pasando a tu función para que luego la agregue a la consulta SQL
$id_articulo = $_REQUEST["id]; //obtienes el id (en el post, get y/o cookies) como parámetro enviado por el usuario al hacer click
$purchase_details=find_purchase_details($id_articulo); //pasas la id

function find_purchase_details($id){
    global $db;
    $sql="SELECT pu.id,p.name AS name,p_d.qty AS qty,p_d.price AS price,p_d.total AS total";
    $sql.=" FROM purchase_details p_d";
    $sql.=" INNER JOIN purchases pu ON p_d.date=pu.date";
    $sql.=" INNER JOIN products p ON p_d.product_id=p.id";
    $sql.=" WHERE pu.id=".$id; //agregas la id que filtra la consulta, si la id es en string no olvides agregar las comillas simples
    return find_by_sql($sql);
}

IMPORTANTE: Este código de arriba tienes serios problemas de seguridad (SQL injection), un mejor código podría ser:
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $id = $_REQUEST["id];


    $sql="SELECT pu.id,p.name AS name,p_d.qty AS qty,p_d.price AS price,p_d.total AS total";
    $sql.=" FROM purchase_details p_d";
    $sql.=" INNER JOIN purchases pu ON p_d.date=pu.date";
    $sql.=" INNER JOIN products p ON p_d.product_id=p.id";
    $sql.=" WHERE pu.id= :id";


    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       
    }

